# visual studio 2008 IDE not displaying UI control properties

Tags: winforms

When I return from debug mode, my visual studio 2008 environment takes a really long time to display the properties of a UI control (e.g. text box) I click on.

why does this happen? Is there a hotfix or update for this from microsoft?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WPF, then this might be normal :) VS doesn't have a very quick WPF UI designer.  Get Expression Blend, its designed for such things.  If you're using WinForms, I'm not sure.  I've often felt slowdowns when using 3rd party WinForms controls, such as Telerik or DevComponent's DotNetBar, but it is because references to these controls bring in huge DLL's of which you often only use a small portion of.  It leads to bloat, which can slow down a UI designer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am experiencing extreme slowness only with the third party UI controls. I am using Infragistics.